# Python pattern replacement

Tags: python

Maybe pattern replacement isn't the right word, but I don't know what else to call it. I want to take a string like "hi my name is *name* and I am a *age* years old" or whatever and fill in the values pragmatically. What's the best way to do that (again, in python)

Comment: [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

You start with a string like this:

```
s = 'Hi my name is {name} and I am {age} years old'
```

Now when you want to, you can use the `str.format` method to "fill in the values".

```
>>> s.format(name='John', age=42)
Hi my name is John and I am 42 years old
```

What this does is replace the things in the braces (`{}`) with the given material.

Note that this method is preferred over using the `%` operator to format, and is the standard in Python 3.

Comment: Ahhh that's it. I knew it was simple. Thanks. Interesting, I can't accept this as the correct answer for 8 more minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
name, age = 'Art', 20

myStr = "hi my name is {0} and I am a {1} years old" 

print myStr.format(name, age)
```

Or:

```
myStr = "hi my name is %(name)s and I am a %(age)i years old" 
print myStr % {'name': name, 'age': age}
```

Or:

```
myStr = "hi my name is %s and I am a %i years old" 
print myStr % (name, age)
```

[Read more on string formatting within python docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at python re http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
>>> import re
>>> thing = "hi my name is placeholder"
>>> thing = re.sub("placeholder", "Fred", thing)
>>> thing
"hi my name is Fred"
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are efficient.
Now I provide a method by using **string Template**.

```
from string import Template
s = Template("hi my name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old")
s.substitute(name='Bill', age=24)
# 'hi my name is Bill and I am 24 years old'
```

You may want to use relevant method **safe_substitute**, and find more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=template#string.Template.substitute).